# How to display bars from left to right with a fixed bar gap?

Tags: recharts

I want to display bars from left to right with a fixed bar gap, rather than display them evenly.

I have tried to add `barCategoryGap` or `barGap` prop with fixed number, but no influence for the chart like this:
[image: chart]

And my code is:

```
<BarChart data={data} barSize={10} barCategoryGap={1}>
        <YAxis
          ...some props
        />
        <Tooltip />
        <Bar dataKey="responseTime">
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <Cell fill={item.isPass ? '#3c763d' : '#a94442'} key={index} />
          ))}
        </Bar>
</BarChart>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your graph, you don't have any XAxis specified to group your bars into categories. Because of this, the props `barGap` and `barCategoryGap` won't work, since there is no category to make changes on.

To solve your problem, you should add the missing XAxis which datakey would be a prop in your data object array, that shares the same object where your `Bar`s values come from so that they can be regrouped. Afterwards you can "play" around with the gap between the different bars, just like a demo found on Recharts for [Bars](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-bar-chart-tpz8r?file=/src/App.tsx:1047-1049).